# Performance configuration seems to be ineffective PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance

I'm not very experienced in databases and i want to increase performance of PostgreSQL query by using configuration. Most of the query takes around `3.5` seconds to be completely searched in logs. Then i checked the configuration file and settings are set to relatively low values, therefore i calculated the best possible configuration and entered it in `psql`:

```
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  max_connections = '200';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  shared_buffers = '4GB';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  effective_cache_size = '12GB';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  work_mem = '20971kB';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  maintenance_work_mem = '1GB';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  min_wal_size = '1GB';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  max_wal_size = '2GB';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  checkpoint_completion_target = '0.7';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  wal_buffers = '16MB';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  default_statistics_target = '100';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET
postgres-#  random_page_cost = '4';
ALTER SYSTEM
```

This didn't work at first, and i thought restarting database was necessary, so i used:

`SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

But there was no progress still. Before configuration `work_mem` was `4 MB` whereas `maintenance_work_mem` was `64 MB` and even after increasing them at these numbers, time taken for the database queries were very similar.

---

**Table**:

Table was created automatically by Django (my web framework), therefore like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "some_char" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
);
```

**Index creation**:

`CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON table USING gist (column gist_trgm_ops);`

**Execution plans (explain and analyze)**:

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on main_question  (cost=1721.05..20990.16 rows=1786 width=436) (actual time=2634.604..2634.634 rows=9 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (attr1 % 'querytext'::text)
   Filter: (char_length(attr2) > 300)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 5
   Heap Blocks: exact=13
   Buffers: shared hit=419319
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..1720.60 rows=5358 width=0) (actual time=2634.578..2634.578 rows=14 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (attr1 % 'querytext'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=419306
 Planning time: 0.131 ms
 Execution time: 2634.739 ms
(11 rows)
```

**Query logs**:

before configuration:

```
(0.000) SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext'; args=None
(3.568) SELECT "main_model"."id", "main_model"."attribute1", "main_model"."attribute2" FROM "main_model" WHERE ((CHAR_LENGTH(attribute2) > 350) AND "main_model"."attribute1" % 'querytext'); args=(u'querytext',)
```

after configuration:

```
(0.000) SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext'; args=None
(3.555) SELECT "main_model"."id", "main_model"."attribute1", "main_model"."attribute2" FROM "main_model" WHERE ((CHAR_LENGTH(attribute2) > 350) AND "main_model"."attribute1" % 'querytext'); args=(u'querytext',)
```

as you can see, query times are very similar for some reason.

---

Shouldn't these settings increase the maximum memory usage thus the performance? Am i doing something incorrectly?

Comment: If you want help with tuning a query you need to show us the query, the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Only `work_mem` and `shared_buffers` will increase memory usage (and changing shared_buffers does require a restart)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Added logs for when query is performed.

Comment: The logs tell us nothing. Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Big apologies for late response, added them all.

Comment: There is sill no execution plan in that question  the output of **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** which will reveal the real runtime of the queries and information on why they might be slow (the log seems to indicate that the query runs in 3ms - that sounds quite fast to me)

Comment: Is that 3ms? or 3 seconds? since i agree that 3ms would be quite fast. Also, added the execution plans after realizing how was it done.